# Combine Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set of markers in a map they are named like this ev1, ev2, ev3 etc.

When I click a link i want a popup to be opened from the map, they are triggered like this,

```
ev1.openPopup();
```

But because I can't write popup code of each marker I got a jquery code like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.venname', function () {
var myLinkId = $('.venname').attr('data-mylink'); 
    ev+myLinkId.openPopup();
});
```

Once a link is clicked it will get an id called data-mylink and will combine it with ev, as an example when I click lick one, it'll have a attribute called 1 and the jquery code will get 1 and make the variavle ev1 and will trigger the popup, but somehow I can't get this thing to work and gets an error ev is not defined.

So how can I combile ev with the variable myLinkID?

Comment: I don't think you can do this. You are trying to variabilize variable name.

Comment: Serially named variables is a strong indication of a flawed data structure. In this case you obviously need an array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use primitive objects or arrays to store marker objects:

```
var markers = {marker1: new Marker(...), marker2: new Marker(...), ... };
```

and then you can reach Marker objects like that:

```
markers['marker'+markerId].openPopup();
```

An array example:

```
var markers = [new Marker(...), new Marker(...), ...];

markers[markerIndex].openPopup();
```